# Linking Sales Ticket and Refund Ticket in Java POS

Tags: javapos, openbravo

In Openbravo POS when I'm refunding a sales ticket (assume its id to be 3980) and when I refund this ticket it generates a new ID(assume it to be 48). So, I want the refund Id(48) to be printed on the sales ticket whenever I do a refund. Does anyone has any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will actually have to modify the ticketline table and add a new column RefundedTicketId and link the ticketline for a sale to the ticketline of the refund. Note that the refund quantity maybe less than the original purchase. I am implementing this right now to prevent duplicate refunds. If anyone is interested i can post the highlight of the code.